# How to implement a "hidden" Android app?

Tags: android

I would like an application which is not readily apparent to casual perusal of the Android.

How best to activate it and bring its screen to the fore? Can I detect a special dialing sequence, like `*1234#`? Or a hotkey combination?

When activated, I guess I can pop up an anonymous screen which does not mention the app, but only asks for a password.

If password is ok, then show the app.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the use case of this?  It sounds a bit malicious.

Comment: I'm not an amazing android developer (yet) but it strikes me that you might find dialing hooks through the intent mechanism. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Comment: @mbaird: it might be used as parental controls, for example. Although I'm sure Android already comes with a good set of those.

Comment: Sipdroid hooks itself into calls endlich with a +, so it's possible.

Comment: "What is the use case of this? It sounds a bit malicious". I'd rather not say, since it is a commercial project, but we have taken legal advice. I can only say that it won't do anything malicious, but we would rather than anyone who finds a lost handset not be aware that the app exists (for security reasons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're simply trying to hide some type of functionality you could mask the application with something very simple like an app that showed a slide show.  You could then listen to key presses or gestures in the mask app and launch the required functionality or application.

Also you could use a service which listens to all sorts of interesting things.  If you ran a background service which listened to incoming sms you could start your application by texting yourself a certain code.

a service could also listen for key presses which are not handled by the top level activity.

There are many ways to do this I suppose though the simple masking app is likely the easiest.

Comment: A service cannot "listen for key presses which are not handled by the top level activity".

Comment: +1 for hiding it behind an innocuous app., Sneaky!!  Me liek!!

Comment: I really thought that was possible.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

An extended reply to tstenner's comment.

You can implement a `BroadcastReceiver` which listens to the `Intent` ['android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL'](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL). Check the docs for more info!

Do not, however, that your application will still be visible in the package manager, as it should be.

Comment: +1 for app still visible in package manager.  I wonder - if I intercept an outgoing call, in order to check for `*1234#`, can I then abandon the call when I recognize my special dial string?  I seem to recall that I can't, so I need to check this.

Comment: SipDroid does this, so yes it is possible. Though I don't know how :).